# Cascading Dropdown in materialTable using react

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am trying to implement cascading dropdown in my code using material-Table in react, By selected programmingLanguage i need to show the related programmingLanguageVersion.

```
let programmingLanguage = ['Java', 'C#', 'Python'];
    const programmingLanguageVersion: Record<string, string[]> = {
        Java: ['1.8', '11'],
        Python: ['11', '15']
    };

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([{
            title: 'Programming Language',
            field: 'programmingLanguage',
            lookup: programmingLanguage,
            editComponent: ({ value, onRowDataChange, rowData }) => (
                <Select
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        onRowDataChange({
                            ...rowData,
                            programmingLanguage: (event.target.value) ?? "",
                            programmingLanguageVersion: ""
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    {programmingLanguage.map((pv) => (
                        <MenuItem key={pv} value={pv}>
                            {pv}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            )
        },
        {
            title: 'Programming Language Version',
            field: 'programmingLanguageVersion',
            lookup: programmingLanguageVersion,
            editComponent: ({ value, onChange, rowData }) => (
                <Select
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        onChange(event.target.value);
                    }}
                >
                    {getVersion(rowData.programmingLanguage).map((programmingLanguage) => (
                        <MenuItem key={programmingLanguage} value={programmingLanguage}>
                            {programmingLanguage}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            ),
        }}])

<MaterialTable
            title={<TemplateTitle variant="h3" text={tempTitle} />}
            icons={tableIcons}
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            style={{
              borderWidth: "1px",
              borderColor: "#AEB2B2",
              width: "140%",
              boxShadow: "none"
            }}
            options={{
              padding: "dense",
              paging: true,
              emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
              actionsColumnIndex: -1,
              headerStyle: { color: "#6b778c", fontSize: "14px", fontWeight: 400 },
              searchFieldStyle: { color: "#172b4d", fontSize: "14px", fontWeight: 400 },
              actionsCellStyle: { border: "none" }
            }}
            components={{
              Toolbar: props => (
                <div className={classes.toolbarWrapper}><MTableToolbar {...props} /></div>
              ),
              Pagination: props => (
                <div className={classes.paginationStyle}><MTablePagination {...props} /></div>
              )
            }},
              onRowAdd: newData =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    props.rowAdd(newData, resolve);
                  }, 1000)
                }),
              onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    props.rowUpdate(newData, oldData, resolve);
                  }, 1000)
                }),
              onRowDelete: oldData =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    props.rowDelete(oldData, resolve);
                  }, 1000)
                }),
            }}
          />
```

But the problem what i am facing after save, the selected value is not displaying in materialTable, when i am clicking on edit i see the selected value. Can anyone please help me to implementing this?